# DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body options[2]: Required options must be placed before non-required options

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Okay guys so after I posted the first question and got no answer, I almost surfed the whole net, formatted the code but still couldn't find a fix.

I keep getting this error when I register about 13-14 slash commands using the `commands.set()` method:

```
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
options[2]: Required options must be placed before non-required options
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Mihir\Desktop\FunMod\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Mihir\Desktop\FunMod\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async GuildApplicationCommandManager.set (C:\Users\Mihir\Desktop\FunMod\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:146:18) {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/applications/922152514420363285/guilds/933052184432636014/commands',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400,
```

This is the source code of the `ready.js` file where I am registering these commands:

```
const { Constants } = require("discord.js")
const {promisify} = require('util')
const {glob} = require('glob')

const globPromise = promisify(glob);

//const slashregister = require('../../slashregistering')
module.exports = async(Discord , client) => {
    console.log('Bot is ready')
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('933052184432636014')
    const commands = guild.commands
    var arrayofCommands = new Array()
    var commands1 = [
        {
            name : 'add',
            description : 'Adds two numbers.',
            options : [{
                name : 'num1',
                description : 'Number1',
                required : true,
                type : Constants.ApplicationCommandOptionTypes.INTEGER
            },
            {
                name : 'num2',
                description : 'Number2',
                required : true,
                type : Constants.ApplicationCommandOptionTypes.INTEGER
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
   
    const slashcommands = await globPromise(`${process.cwd()}/slashcommands/**/*.js`)
    slashcommands.map((file) => {
        const value = require(file)
        //delete value.execute
        console.log(value)
        
        arrayofCommands.push(value)
    })
     commands.set(
        arrayofCommands
     )
}
```

However, the code should work since the 'file' variable has all the required fields: `name`, `description`, `type`, `defaultPermission`, and `options` too.

So I outputted the object `file` and this is one of its iterations:

[image]

And the surprising thing is that the `commands1` array, although having the same properties as that of `arrayOfCommands` array, WORKS! So could anyone please help me?

Here is the full error:

```
Server is online!
Bot is ready
C:\Users\Mihir\Desktop\FunMod\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
options[2]: Required options must be placed before non-required options
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Mihir\Desktop\FunMod\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Mihir\Desktop\FunMod\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async GuildApplicationCommandManager.set (C:\Users\Mihir\Desktop\FunMod\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:146:18) {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/applications/922152514420363285/guilds/933052184432636014/commands',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: [
      {
        name: 'addrole',
        description: 'Gives the member a role.',
        type: 1,
        options: [
          {
            type: 8,
            name: 'role',
            description: 'Role Name',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          },
          {
            type: 6,
            name: 'member',
            description: 'Member ',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          }
        ],
        default_permission: false
      },
      {
        name: 'ban',
        description: 'Ban the specified member.',
        type: 1,
        options: [
          {
            type: 6,
            name: 'member',
            description: 'Member ',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          },
          {
            type: 3,
            name: 'reason',
            description: 'Reason ',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          }
        ],
        default_permission: false
      },
      {
        name: 'changenick',
        description: 'Changes the nickname of a server member.',
        type: 1,
        options: [
          {
            type: 6,
            name: 'member',
            description: 'Member',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          },
          {
            type: 3,
            name: 'nickname',
            description: 'Nickname',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          }
        ],
        default_permission: false
      },
      {
        name: 'kick',
        description: 'Kicks the specified member.',
        type: 1,
        options: [
          {
            type: 6,
            name: 'member',
            description: 'Member',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          },
          {
            type: 3,
            name: 'reason',
            description: 'Reason',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          }
        ],
        default_permission: false
      },
      {
        name: 'lock',
        description: 'Locks the specified channel for the specified role.',
        type: 1,
        options: [
          {
            type: 7,
            name: 'channel',
            description: 'Channel',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          },
          {
            type: 8,
            name: 'role',
            description: 'Role ',
            required: false,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          }
        ],
        default_permission: false
      },
      {
        name: 'lockdown',
        description: 'Enforces a complete lockdown on the server.',
        type: 1,
        options: [
          {
            type: 3,
            name: 'toggle',
            description: 'on/off',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          },
          {
            type: 8,
            name: 'role',
            description: 'Role ',
            required: false,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          }
        ],
        default_permission: false
      },
      {
        name: 'removerole',
        description: 'Removes role from a member.',
        type: 1,
        options: [
          {
            type: 6,
            name: 'member',
            description: 'Member ',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          },
          {
            type: 8,
            name: 'role',
            description: 'Role ',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          }
        ],
        default_permission: false
      },
      {
        name: 'timeout',
        description: 'Gives a member a timeout.',
        type: 1,
        options: [
          {
            type: 6,
            name: 'member',
            description: 'Member ',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          },
          {
            type: 3,
            name: 'reason',
            description: 'Reason',
            required: false,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          },
          {
            type: 3,
            name: 'time',
            description: 'Duration',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          }
        ],
        default_permission: false
      },
      {
        name: 'unlock',
        description: 'Locks the specified channel for the specified role.',
        type: 1,
        options: [
          {
            type: 7,
            name: 'channel',
            description: 'Channel',
            required: false,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          },
          {
            type: 8,
            name: 'role',
            description: 'Role',
            required: false,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          }
        ],
        default_permission: false
      },
      {
        name: 'embedcreate',
        description: 'Creates an embed.',
        type: 1,
        options: [
          {
            type: 7,
            name: 'channel',
            description: 'Channel ',
            required: false,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          },
          {
            type: 3,
            name: 'color',
            description: 'Hex-Code',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          },
          {
            type: 3,
            name: 'title',
            description: 'Title',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          }
        ],
        default_permission: false
      },
      {
        name: 'ping',
        description: 'Responds with a pong!',
        type: 1,
        options: undefined,
        default_permission: false
      },
      {
        name: 'setactivity',
        description: 'Sets the Activity of the bot.',
        type: 1,
        options: [
          {
            type: 3,
            name: 'activity',
            description: 'Activity',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          },
          {
            type: 3,
            name: 'type',
            description: 'Type ',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          }
        ],
        default_permission: false
      },
      {
        name: 'setavatar',
        description: "Sets the bot's avatar.",
        type: 1,
        options: [
          {
            type: 3,
            name: 'link',
            description: 'Image Link',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          }
        ],
        default_permission: false
      },
      {
        name: 'setstatus',
        description: 'Sets the status of the bot.',
        type: 1,
        options: [
          {
            type: 3,
            name: 'status',
            description: 'Status ',
            required: true,
            autocomplete: undefined,
            choices: undefined,
            options: undefined,
            channel_types: undefined,
            min_value: undefined,
            max_value: undefined
          }
        ],
        default_permission: false
      }
    ],
    files: []
  }
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: I don't think the error message and the logged file match. The error is about a command with (at least) three options and your lock command has only two.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Oh okay but only name and description are the mandatory
https://pastebin.pl/view/48cff071 This is the link to the complete error code.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error is trying to tell you is that you can't have required options after non-required ones. In your `requestData` you can see all your `options` arrays. Check out the one for your `timeout` command:

```js
{
  name: 'timeout',
  description: 'Gives a member a timeout.',
  type: 1,
  options: [
    {
      type: 6,
      name: 'member',
      description: 'Member ',
      required: true,
      autocomplete: undefined,
      choices: undefined,
      options: undefined,
      channel_types: undefined,
      min_value: undefined,
      max_value: undefined
    },
    {
      type: 3,
      name: 'reason',
      description: 'Reason',
      required: false,
      autocomplete: undefined,
      choices: undefined,
      options: undefined,
      channel_types: undefined,
      min_value: undefined,
      max_value: undefined
    },
    {
      type: 3,
      name: 'time',
      description: 'Duration',
      required: true,
      autocomplete: undefined,
      choices: undefined,
      options: undefined,
      channel_types: undefined,
      min_value: undefined,
      max_value: undefined
    }
  ],
  default_permission: false
}
```

Can you see that the first option (`member`) is required, the second one (`reason`) is not required, and the last one (`time`) is required again?

It should be ordered like this; first the two required fields, and last the non-required:

```js
{
  name: 'timeout',
  description: 'Gives a member a timeout.',
  type: 1,
  options: [
    {
      type: 6,
      name: 'member',
      description: 'Member',
      required: true,
      autocomplete: undefined,
      choices: undefined,
      options: undefined,
      channel_types: undefined,
      min_value: undefined,
      max_value: undefined
    },
    {
      type: 3,
      name: 'time',
      description: 'Duration',
      required: true,
      autocomplete: undefined,
      choices: undefined,
      options: undefined,
      channel_types: undefined,
      min_value: undefined,
      max_value: undefined
    },
    {
      type: 3,
      name: 'reason',
      description: 'Reason',
      required: false,
      autocomplete: undefined,
      choices: undefined,
      options: undefined,
      channel_types: undefined,
      min_value: undefined,
      max_value: undefined
    }
  ],
  default_permission: false
}
```

Also, the order is wrong for your `embedcreate` command. Change the order of the options there too:

```js
{
  name: 'embedcreate',
  description: 'Creates an embed.',
  type: 1,
  options: [
    {
      type: 3,
      name: 'color',
      description: 'Hex-Code',
      required: true,
      autocomplete: undefined,
      choices: undefined,
      options: undefined,
      channel_types: undefined,
      min_value: undefined,
      max_value: undefined
    },
    {
      type: 3,
      name: 'title',
      description: 'Title',
      required: true,
      autocomplete: undefined,
      choices: undefined,
      options: undefined,
      channel_types: undefined,
      min_value: undefined,
      max_value: undefined
    },
    {
      type: 7,
      name: 'channel',
      description: 'Channel ',
      required: false,
      autocomplete: undefined,
      choices: undefined,
      options: undefined,
      channel_types: undefined,
      min_value: undefined,
      max_value: undefined
    }
  ],
  default_permission: false
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your help !! It worked :)) I failed to notice the error before 